# why cant we change object itself through this while object property can be changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to know the reason why can't we change the object itself?

```js
var obj = {
  a: "hello"
};

function modify(o) {
  o = {
    a: "hello world"
  };
}

modify(obj);
console.log(obj.a);
```

Comment: you are overwriting the reference in the function scope while changing properties changes the value in the reference

Comment: This can be confusing, I would take a look at some docs or blogs and play with your example until it makes sense. The idea is that object variables are references to objects, but are not exactly objects themselves. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `modify(o)` you are assigning the variable `o` a new object reference, leaving the original `obj` untouched.

If you want to modify the original object, access it directly:

```
var obj = { a: "hello" };

function modify(o) {
  o.a = "hello world" // this modifies the object passed to the function
}

modify(obj);
console.log(obj.a);
```